# ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Gui.WpfWorkbench - Can't find the containing assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, using, wpftoolkit, sharpdevelop

I write a plugin in C#, where the hosting application handles me an instance of `WpfWorkbench` in order to allow me to add contols to it's UI (it's actually sort of a hack... anyway I get the `WpfWorkbench` instance in runtime).

Problem is, I can't cast the returned object from `Window` to `WpfWorkbench` in my code, since I don't have the `ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Gui` namespace reference in my project.

I have downloaded [`SharpDevelop 4.4` framework](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/#SharpDevelop4x) and tried to find the class reference in it's Dll's, but was unsuccessful.

I'm not an experienced VS user, so I think I might just missed an obvious thing. Should I expect to find the `GUI` namespace in the framework? Or is it some sort of an Add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharpDevelop 4.4 the WpfWorkbench is in the ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.dll. However WpfWorkbench is an internal class so it will not be available to you unless you use reflection.

What exactly are you trying to do? There might be another way to do it. Usually SharpDevelop is extended through its addin system using an .addin file.

Comment: You are right! I figured this out a couple of hours ago, and have already made the required changes to the `.addin` file. I added the menu items and registered my dll as handler. Thanks!